# request returns status 404 or 415 when using json

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a couple of web services calls using the `request` package in python one is purely form and WORKS:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/coordinator/finished-crawl', \
                   data = {'competitorId':value})
```

And the other uses JSON and does not work:

```
service_url = 'http://localhost:5000/coordinator/save-page'
data = {'Url': url, 'CompetitorId': competitorID, \
        'Fetched': self.generateTimestamp(), 'Html': html}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(service_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Now if do not include headers I use the headers as above, I get a 404, but if I do not include as

```
r = requests.post(service_url, data=json.dumps(data))
```

I get a 415. I have tried looking at other post on stackoverflow and from what I can tell the call is correct. I have tested the web service via the application postman and it works. Can some tell me what is wrong or point me in the right direction?

**THE FULL METHOD**

```
def saveContent(self, url, competitorID, html):
    temp = self.cleanseHtml(html)
    service_url = 'http://localhost:5000/coordinator/save-page'
    data = {'Url': url, 'CompetitorId': competitorID, \
            'Fetched': self.generateTimestamp(), \
            'Html': temp}
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(service_url, json=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

## r = requests.post(service_url, json=json.dumps(data))

And cleanseHTML:

```
def cleanseHtml(self, html):
    return html.replace("\\", "\\\\")\
               .replace("\"", "\\\"")\
               .replace("\n", "")\
               .replace("\r", "")
```

Comment: Are you sure that `url`, `competitorID`, `self.generateTimestamp()`, `html` are valid values? Can you try same request with exact values you want to send to server?

Comment: @Andersson okay the html contains " which I forgot to escape, which I just tried to. But it just result in getting 404 in stead

Comment: I have added the full function call and a helper function

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the cause of your issue, but you don't need to specify `json=json.dumps(data)`, but `json=data` or `data=json.dumps(data)` instead

Comment: @Andersson THANKS!!!!!! Fixed